# Optimize performance of MySQL for XML parsing

Tags: php, mysql, xml, performance, indices

I'm working on a project to decrease the load time of a page. The PHP script that runs establishes a connection to the database. It then receives a XML file, and stores each element in a variable. A query is then run to check if a "member ID" exists, and if it doesn't, inserts all of the data from the XML in a very long INSERT statement (20 columns). The process repeats a second time for a different table on the same database, UPDATE if already existing, INSERTING if not found.

Whats the most optimal way to speed up these queries or tune them so that they can run faster? I'm currently looking into using indices, but I'm not sure how they work or how to implement them. Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks

Here's some sample code:

```
$partner_insert  = "INSERT INTO `keystore`.`partners` SET ";
$partner_insert .= "`ma_id`='1', `partner_name`='".$member_name."', `partner_email`='".$member_name."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`member_id`='".$member_id."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`member_billingname`='".$member_billingname."', `member_billingconfirstname`='".$member_billingconfirstname."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`member_billingconlastname`='".$member_billingconlastname."', `member_billingcurrency`='".$member_billingcurrency."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`member_billingaddress`='".$member_billingaddress."', `member_billingcity`='".$member_billingcity."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`member_billingcountry`='".$member_billingcountry."', `member_billingzipcode`='".$member_billingzipcode."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`member_billingstate`='".$member_billingstate."', `member_billingstatecode`='".$member_billingstatecode."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`member_billingprimaryemail`='".$member_billingprimaryemail."', `member_billingprimaryphone`='".$member_billingprimaryphone."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`member_billingsecondaryphone`='".$member_billingsecondaryphone."', `last_action_by`='".$ndp_id."', ";
$partner_insert .= "`last_action_date`=NOW(), `last_action`='Create'"
```

Comment: Provide some of your sample code here.

Comment: How big is the data in the table? Did you try profiling the script to know which portions of the code takes more time?! My guess would be the xml parsing.

Also, what are the column types you are using?! Can you post the table schema?

If you have a high writing rate, applying indexes to the tables can actually slow you down!

Comment: @MosabAhmad how do I go about profiling the script?

Comment: This would be a great series of articles to read on PHP debugging and profiling : http://devzone.zend.com/1120/introducing-xdebug/

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inserts will be slow. It rather sounds as though you can batch up the inserts and do hundreds at a time. If you do this you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax to do an INSERT or UPDATE depending on whether the row exists.

Making massive guesses as to you actual data (such as what is the key that decides if things are a duplicate to update rather than insert), something like this:-

```
<?php

$insert_array = array();

foreach($members as $member)
{
    if (count($insert_array) > 250)
    {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO keystone.partners (member_name, member_id, member_billingname, member_billingconfirstname, member_billingconlastname, member_billingcurrency, member_billingaddress, member_billingcity, member_billingcountry, member_billingzipcode, member_billingstate, member_billingstatecode, member_billingprimaryemail, member_billingprimaryphone, member_billingsecondaryphone, ndp_id)".
                    implode(",", $insert_array).
                    "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE member_name=VALUES(member_name),  member_billingname=VALUES(member_billingname), member_billingconfirstname=VALUES(member_billingconfirstname), member_billingconlastname=VALUES(member_billingconlastname), member_billingcurrency=VALUES(member_billingcurrency), member_billingaddress=VALUES(member_billingaddress), member_billingcity=VALUES(member_billingcity), member_billingcountry=VALUES(member_billingcountry), member_billingzipcode=VALUES(member_billingzipcode), member_billingstate=VALUES(member_billingstate), member_billingstatecode=VALUES(member_billingstatecode), member_billingprimaryemail=VALUES(member_billingprimaryemail), member_billingprimaryphone=VALUES(member_billingprimaryphone), member_billingsecondaryphone=VALUES(member_billingsecondaryphone), ndp_id=VALUES(ndp_id)");
    $insert_array = array();
    }
    $member_name                    = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_name']);
    $member_id                      = (int)$member['member_id'];
    $member_billingname             = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingname']);
    $member_billingconfirstname     = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingconfirstname']);
    $member_billingconlastname      = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingconlastname']);
    $member_billingcurrency         = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingcurrency']);
    $member_billingaddress          = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingaddress']);
    $member_billingcity             = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingcity']);
    $member_billingcountry          = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingcountry']);
    $member_billingzipcode          = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingzipcode']);
    $member_billingstate            = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingstate']);
    $member_billingstatecode        = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingstatecode']);
    $member_billingprimaryemail     = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingprimaryemail']);
    $member_billingprimaryphone     = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingprimaryphone']);
    $member_billingsecondaryphone   = $db->real_escape_string($member['member_billingsecondaryphone']);
    $ndp_id                         = (int)$member['ndp_id'];
    $insert_array[] =   "('$member_name', $member_id','$member_billingname','$member_billingconfirstname','$member_billingconlastname','$member_billingcurrency','$member_billingaddress','$member_billingcity','$member_billingcountry','$member_billingzipcode','$member_billingstate','$member_billingstatecode','$member_billingprimaryemail','$member_billingprimaryphone','$member_billingsecondaryphone',$ndp_id)";
}

$db->query("INSERT INTO keystone.partners (member_name, member_id, member_billingname, member_billingconfirstname, member_billingconlastname, member_billingcurrency, member_billingaddress, member_billingcity, member_billingcountry, member_billingzipcode, member_billingstate, member_billingstatecode, member_billingprimaryemail, member_billingprimaryphone, member_billingsecondaryphone, ndp_id)".
            implode(",", $insert_array).
            "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE member_name=VALUES(member_name),  member_billingname=VALUES(member_billingname), member_billingconfirstname=VALUES(member_billingconfirstname), member_billingconlastname=VALUES(member_billingconlastname), member_billingcurrency=VALUES(member_billingcurrency), member_billingaddress=VALUES(member_billingaddress), member_billingcity=VALUES(member_billingcity), member_billingcountry=VALUES(member_billingcountry), member_billingzipcode=VALUES(member_billingzipcode), member_billingstate=VALUES(member_billingstate), member_billingstatecode=VALUES(member_billingstatecode), member_billingprimaryemail=VALUES(member_billingprimaryemail), member_billingprimaryphone=VALUES(member_billingprimaryphone), member_billingsecondaryphone=VALUES(member_billingsecondaryphone), ndp_id=VALUES(ndp_id)");

?>
```